# Modx and Ditto module: What is "parents"?

Tags: php, content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution

This is an extremely novice question :)

I'm working on a website that is built in [Modx](http://modx.com/). There is a page where it lists 3 job listings which are essentially links to pdf files. I was able to find the piece of code that creates this template and I understand that It's using a module called Ditto to do this. I just don't understand what the "parents" is, where it's defined and how it's created.

Here is the piece of code:

```
[[Ditto? &parents=`107` &tpl=`careers_list` &orderBy=`adate DESC`]]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/Ditto_2.1_parameters#.26parents

Comment: Please at least try to find some documentation before asking for help here...

Comment: I did, and I read multiple documentations including the one you gave above, but my problem is I can's find where that " ID(s) of documents containing documents and sub-folders from which to retrieve data" is set. In the admin or in the file structure? I can't seem to find it in neither place.